# routing issue on nopCommerce 2.3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, nopcommerce

I'm having problems debugging what I think is a routing issue on nopCommerce 2.3.

Both the sitemap and search pages redirect to the homepage instead of their respective pages. This is the code in the RouteProvider.cs:

```
    //product search
    routes.MapLocalizedRoute("ProductSearch", "search/", new { controller = "Catalog", action = "Search" }, new[] { "Nop.Web.Controllers" });
```

This is the CatalogController.cs code:

```
    public ActionResult Search(SearchModel model, SearchPagingFilteringModel command)
    {
        if (model == null)
            model = new SearchModel();

        if (command.PageSize <= 0) command.PageSize = _catalogSettings.SearchPageProductsPerPage;
        if (command.PageNumber <= 0) command.PageNumber = 1;
        if (model.Q == null)
            model.Q = "";
        model.Q = model.Q.Trim();

        var categories = _categoryService.GetAllCategories();
        if (categories.Count > 0)
        {
            model.AvailableCategories.Add(new SelectListItem()
                {
                     Value = "0",
                     Text = _localizationService.GetResource("Common.All")
                });
            foreach(var c in categories)
                model.AvailableCategories.Add(new SelectListItem()
                    {
                        Value = c.Id.ToString(),
                        Text = c.GetCategoryBreadCrumb(_categoryService),
                        Selected = model.Cid == c.Id
                    });
        }

        var manufacturers = _manufacturerService.GetAllManufacturers();
        if (manufacturers.Count > 0)
        {
            model.AvailableManufacturers.Add(new SelectListItem()
            {
                Value = "0",
                Text = _localizationService.GetResource("Common.All")
            });
            foreach (var m in manufacturers)
                model.AvailableManufacturers.Add(new SelectListItem()
                {
                    Value = m.Id.ToString(),
                    Text = m.Name,
                    Selected = model.Mid == m.Id
                });
        }

        IPagedList<Product> products = new PagedList<Product>(new List<Product>(), 0, 1);
        // only search if query string search keyword is set (used to avoid searching or displaying search term min length error message on /search page load)
        if (Request.Params["Q"] != null)
        {
            if (model.Q.Length < _catalogSettings.ProductSearchTermMinimumLength)
            {
                model.Warning = string.Format(_localizationService.GetResource("Search.SearchTermMinimumLengthIsNCharacters"), _catalogSettings.ProductSearchTermMinimumLength);
            }
            else
            {
                int categoryId = 0;
                int manufacturerId = 0;
                decimal? minPriceConverted = null;
                decimal? maxPriceConverted = null;
                bool searchInDescriptions = false;
                if (model.As)
                {
                    //advanced search
                    categoryId = model.Cid;
                    manufacturerId = model.Mid;

                    //min price
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Pf))
                    {
                        decimal minPrice = decimal.Zero;
                        if (decimal.TryParse(model.Pf, out minPrice))
                            minPriceConverted = _currencyService.ConvertToPrimaryStoreCurrency(minPrice, _workContext.WorkingCurrency);
                    }
                    //max price
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Pt))
                    {
                        decimal maxPrice = decimal.Zero;
                        if (decimal.TryParse(model.Pt, out maxPrice))
                            maxPriceConverted = _currencyService.ConvertToPrimaryStoreCurrency(maxPrice, _workContext.WorkingCurrency);
                    }

                    searchInDescriptions = model.Sid;
                }

                //products

                // RedMorello 170212 - Change from .Position to .Price
                products = _productService.SearchProducts(categoryId, manufacturerId, null,
                    minPriceConverted, maxPriceConverted, 0,
                    model.Q, searchInDescriptions, _workContext.WorkingLanguage.Id, null,
                ProductSortingEnum.Price, command.PageNumber - 1, command.PageSize);
                model.Products = products.Select(x => PrepareProductOverviewModel(x)).ToList();

                model.NoResults = !model.Products.Any();                    
            }
        }

        model.PagingFilteringContext.LoadPagedList(products);
        return View(model);
    }

    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult SearchBox()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }
```

Comment: Have you had a look in the nopCommerce log to see if any errors get logged? Also, are you using a standard nopCommerce installation, or have you customized the code?